# Mongoose query to find users where a location is less than or equal to the distance the user is willing to travel from the user's location

Tags: mongoose

I am building a web app for a recruiter. A user is one of the recruiter's candidates.

The recruiter will enter the location of a role, e.g., Oxford Street, London.

The client will make a GET request to api/users/:location

In my controller method for the route, I will get the coordinates for the location.

How can I create a Mongoose query to find users, where the location is less than or equal to the distance the user is willing to travel from the user's location or the user is willing to relocate

```
const UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  location: {
    type: {
      type: String,
      enum: ['Point']
    },
    coordinates: {
      type: [Number],
      index: '2dsphere'
    },
    formattedAddress: String,
    street: String,
    city: String,
    state: String,
    zipcode: String,
    country: String
  },
  milesWillingToTravel: Number,
  isWillingToRelocate: {
    type: Boolean,
    default: false
  }
});
```

Comment: What have you done so far and what is your particular problem?

Comment: Hey Random Guy! So far I have built the entire back end except for this route which requires a relatively complex Mongoose query. For each user, first I need to check if they are willing to relocate. If they are willing to relocate, include them in the response, else I need to check how many miles are between the user and the location of the role. If the distance between is less than or equal to the miles the user is willing to travel include them in the response.